# MySQL-define index for select query which has (inner join, CTE and partitions)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb

I have 2 tables in my db: `subscriptions` and `companies`. the following query is supposed to be run:

```
WITH ranked_rows
AS
    (
        SELECT
            s.*
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, company_id ORDER BY insert_timestamp DESC) AS rn
        FROM
            subscriptions AS s
        WHERE
            token = 300
            AND expire_timestamp>=... 
            AND expire_timestamp<...

    )
SELECT
    rr.*
    , c.name
    , c.activity_plan
FROM
    ranked_rows          AS rr
    INNER JOIN comapnies AS c
        ON rr.company_id = c.id
WHERE
    rr.rn = 1
    AND c.activity_plan = 1
    AND c.is_active = true
ORDER BY
    c.insert_timestamp;
```

I have defined the following indexes:

```
subscriptions table:
(token, expire_timestamp)
(insert_timestamp)
(company_id)

companies table:
(id)
(insert_timestamp)
(activity_plan, is_active)
```

my question is that are these indexes enough and optimised for this query? should I define another composite index as `(activity_plan, is_active, insert_timestamp)`? what if the last line of the query was `ORDER BY rr.insert_timestamp` insted of `ORDER BY c.insert_timestamp`?

Comment: Try to execute the SELECT query with the keyword "EXPLAIN" at the beginning: "EXPLAIN SELECT .....". This will show you which indexes are used when executing this query. Maybe this shows you some hints.

Comment: TBH: I would also create an index over user_id, company_id in the subscriptions table. And I hope that the foreignkeys are well defined which are used in the inner join clause. This is important bcz if these keys are NOT defined then no index is available.

Comment: @ErhardDinhobl many thanks for your comments. `subscriptions` table has an index on `company_id` and `companies` table has an index on `id`, but no foreign key relation has been defined for them. does defining foreign key has any positive impact in this case?

Comment: if they have an index then its fine. But a foreign key defintion is better. just experiment with it.